# UISplitView with multiple ViewControllers in DetailView (storyboard)

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard, detailview, uisplitview

i'am looking for a solution to have a UISplitView with multiple ViewControllers inside the DetailView(rightView of the UISplitView).

The example of apple works fine but uses nib file instead of storyboards. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/multipledetailviews/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)

I found another example but there is whitespace when i implement an UITableView
http://www.dharmaworks.net/Consulting/switching-detail-views-in-uisplitviewcontroller-with-ios7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the search for an answer i found many people with the same issue. I figured it out myself so here is my solution. I hope it is useful for other people.

**Step 1.** Create a SplitViewController project. If you have a project already skip this step ;)
[image]

**Step 2.**
Add two different viewControllers. In this case i call them AbcViewController and XyzViewController.
[image]
[image]

**Step 3.**
Go to the ipad storyboard, remove the DetailViewController from the storyboard. Then add two new viewControllers.

[image]

**Step 4.**
Set the class and the Storyboard ID for your viewControllers.
[image]

**Step 5.**
Go to your MasterViewController.h and replace the code with the code below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AbcViewController;
@class XyzViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) AbcViewController *abcViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) XyzViewController *xyzViewController;

@end
```

**Step 6.**
Now go to your MasterViewController.m file and replace with this code:

**Note:** If you have an existing project and don't want to replace use the code in step 7.

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController*)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"ABC";
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"XYZ";
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.abcViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ABC"];
    self.xyzViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"XYZ"];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSArray *newVCs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[self splitViewController ] viewControllers ] firstObject ] , self.abcViewController, nil];
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = newVCs;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        NSArray *newVCs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[self splitViewController ] viewControllers ] firstObject ] , self.xyzViewController, nil];
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = newVCs;
    }
}

@end
```

**Step 7.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        self.abcViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ABC"];
        self.xyzViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"XYZ"];

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            NSArray *newVCs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[self splitViewController ] viewControllers ] firstObject ] , self.abcViewController, nil];
            self.splitViewController.viewControllers = newVCs;
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            NSArray *newVCs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[self splitViewController ] viewControllers ] firstObject ] , self.xyzViewController, nil];
            self.splitViewController.viewControllers = newVCs;
        }
    }
```

---

Thats it, run your project and enjoy :)